# import arcpy in multiprocessing make script to hang indefinitely

Tags: arcpy, python

I have a simple script to test multiprocessing with arcpy, but the script hang indefinitely. The problem is with the `import arcpy` statement that seems to be a problem in the child processes. Other multiprocessing script without `import arcpy` are working correctly

```
import arcpy
import multiprocessing

import os, sys
multiprocessing.set_executable(os.path.join(sys.exec_prefix, 'python.exe'))


def testExists(data):
    print data
    return arcpy.Exists("foo.gdb")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = ["foo.gdb", "bar.gdb"]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    result_arrays = pool.map(testExists, data)
    print result_arrays
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Any idea what can cause the problem?

Comment: FYI I tested on my end and it worked.

Comment: Could it be a license problem?

Comment: @EmilBrundage have you tested from a cmd prompt or from a toolbox?

Comment: I tested from IDLE

Comment: @BelowtheRadar Are you sure it's hanging indefinitely and not hiding an error somehow?  When I run from IDLE it works fine, but when I run it from a toolbox it first appears to be hanging and then I see there is an error in the toolbox output `PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805244/5754917

Comment: On my side it is hanging when running from IDLE